# Why is the non persistent ejb timer not triggering?

Tags: websphere, ejb-3.1, ejb-timer

I'm trying to replace an existing logic in our application that makes use of persistent proggramatic timers to non persistent timers due to a recent issue that we encountered.
The file system that WAS uses to write the persistent information of the timers was full and the Derby database got restarted in read only mode , making our application not able to trigger the timers post that, we had to restart the server to fix the same.

this is the current piece of code that is used to trigger the programmatic timer

```
Timer timer = timerService.createTimer(100,eventContextWrapper);
```

As per the examples quoted in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html, changed our code to

```
TimerConfig tC = new TimerConfig(eventContextWrapper, false);
Timer timer = timerService.createSingleActionTimer(100,  tC);
```

but we are facing the below exception

```
[5/31/17 22:18:23:348 GMT+08:00] 000000bf SystemErr     R org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Unable to read value from underlying bridge : null  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 896  completed: No
[5/31/17 22:18:23:348 GMT+08:00] 000000bf SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDRReader.read_value(CDRReader.java:771)
[5/31/17 22:18:23:348 GMT+08:00] 000000bf SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.EncoderInputStream.read_value(EncoderInputStream.java:840)
[5/31/17 22:18:23:348 GMT+08:00] 000000bf SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.util.ORBObjectCopierImpl.copy(ORBObjectCopierImpl.java:52)
[5/31/17 22:18:23:348 GMT+08:00] 000000bf SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.util.ObjectUtil.copy(ObjectUtil.java:159)
[5/31/17 22:18:23:349 GMT+08:00] 000000bf SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ejs.container.TimerNpImpl.<init>(TimerNpImpl.java:240)
[5/31/17 22:18:23:349 GMT+08:00] 000000bf SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ejs.container.TimerNpImpl.<init>(TimerNpImpl.java:276)
[5/31/17 22:18:23:349 GMT+08:00] 000000bf SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.WASEJBRuntimeImpl.createTimer(WASEJBRuntimeImpl.java:1371)
[5/31/17 22:18:23:349 GMT+08:00] 000000bf SystemErr     R       at com.ibm.ejs.container.BeanO.createSingleActionTimer(BeanO.java:2551)
com.test.customer.event.EventTimerBean.triggerTimer(EventTimerBean.java:62)
```

Line 62 is where the createSingleActionTimer is invoked.

Have done some analysis and unable to fix the same. any lead would be helpful..

Comment: The error is happening while trying to deserialize your context object.  The error message is indecipherable, so if you need more assistance, you should probably open a PMR with IBM.

Comment: @BrettKail Sure, will try raising a PMR with IBM to get assistance from them and update on the progress.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found that one of the classes in the EventContextWrapper is not serializable and that's why we were getting the above error. We changed that class to implement serializable and it worked. Still ain't sure , how come it worked when  persistent timer was used.